# How to reference parent parameters of an anonymous function Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, anonymous-function

I'm trying to figure out how I can reference an argument on a wrapper function stored in a variable that calls an anonymous function. Such as in the example below. The problem I run into is I'm used to accessing parameters via the arguments variable, but that sees only the parameter myFunc. I know it's supposed to be possible, but I can't figure out how.

```
var myFunc = function(arg1, arg2){//do stuff}
var myFuncWrapped = wrapper(myFunc);

myFuncWrapped('arg value1', 'arg value2');

function wrapper(func){
  //how can I reference 'arg value1' from here since arguments == myFunc?
}
```

Comment: In the code you posted `myFuncWrapped` will contain the result of `wrapper(func)`. So, if you want this code to work right, `wrapper` should return a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggested, `wrapper` should be returning a function so you can capture the arguments via [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) when `myFuncWrapped` gets called.

```
var myFunc = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1); // (For testing only) Should be"arg value1"
};

var myFuncWrapped = wrapper(myFunc);

myFuncWrapped('arg value1', 'arg value2');

function wrapper(func) {
    /* The anonymous function below is actually the one
     * being called when you invoke "myFuncWrapped" so it has the arguments you need.
     */
    return function() {
        console.log(arguments[0]); // (For testing only) Should be"arg value1"
        func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more explanation text would be nice

Comment: Sorry yes. Adding it now. :)